# Remove Yarn/NVM/Node from Mac OS

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, macos-catalina, nvm

I am experiencing errors on the ng-validation packages when trying to yarn install a project.
Installed the same project on multiple machines and it worked fine.
The setup used was:

```
brew install nvm
brew install yarn --ignore-dependencies
nvm install 10.15
nvm use 10.15
```

I wan to remove any files/config associated with node/yarn/nvm and maybe reset the .zshrc file to initial state.

Things that i have done:
brew uninstall --force yarn
brew uninstall --force nvm

Removed folders related to node/npm/.nvm/.yarn from /usr/local and ~; any node_modules folders.

I am 100% missing something that i should delete since the project compiles with no problems on other machines, i even installed a clean mac os into a virtual machine and just installed nvm and yarn via brew and it worked perfectly.

The error i am receiving when compiling on my machine is the following:

```
Compiling ng2-validation : main as commonjs
Error: Error on worker #2: Error: Symbol Base64Validator declared in /Users/danproject/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/base64/directive.js is not exported from /Users/dan (import into /Users/dan/project/node_modules/ng2-validation/dist/index.js)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic problem, and not yours alone. The TL/DR of it is that over time it is impossible for multiple systems to run software predictably - you're going to have conflicting OS's, node versions, package managers, et al - all of them leaving traces of themselves somewhere in your hard drive. As soon as one fails (as yours has), then you should assume that any system could fail any day. The fact that it works on some systems and not others is more of a fluke than anything - a spinning plate of sorts.

After running into this issue at my last company where we had Windows, Mac, and Linux machines, all of different flavors - I finally got fed up. I have recently started using docker to run my applications for development, testing, and production. And the only negative feedback I can give is that I wished I had started doing it sooner.

I will admit, it's a little intimidating at first. But I promise you that one you get a couple docker configurations that suit your needs, you will never look back... nor will you ever have to deal with this problem ever again. Here is a simple example to get started. Be patient and give it time:

https://dev.to/numtostr/running-react-and-node-js-in-one-shot-with-docker-3o09